# How to classify my array of object compared to my table?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to reorder my array of object, I want it follows (const quote) the theme position (const themeOrder).

```
const quote = [{
  theme: 'spirituality'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'military'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'tech'
}];
const themeOrder = ['tech', 'politic', 'military', 'spirituality'];
```

I want a result like

```
newQuote = [{
  theme: 'tech'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'military'
}, {
  theme: 'spirituality'
}]
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the `sort` array method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `sort()` the elements based on their index in `themeOrder`:

```
quote.sort((x,y) => themeOrder.indexOf(x.theme) > themeOrder.indexOf(y.theme) ? 1 : -1))
```

See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Shouldn't that be: `quote.sort(x => 0 - themeOrder.indexOf(x.theme))`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to argue with 3 upvotes in half a minute, but as far as I can tell your code doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, You were right. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your array objects with [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by comparing the `theme` properties' index positions in the `themeOrder` array:

```js
const quote = [{
  theme: 'spirituality'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'military'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'tech'
}];
const themeOrder = ['tech', 'politic', 'military', 'spirituality'];

quote.sort((a, b) => themeOrder.indexOf(a.theme) - themeOrder.indexOf(b.theme));

console.log(quote);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to create key/value pairs of theme/order (index). When you sort, translate the theme names to the index numbers, and sort by these values.

```js
const quote = [{
  theme: 'spirituality'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'military'
}, {
  theme: 'politic'
}, {
  theme: 'tech'
}];

const themeOrder = ['tech', 'politic', 'military', 'spirituality'];
const order = themeOrder.reduce((map, key, index) => map.set(key, index), new Map());

quote.sort((a, b) => order.get(a.theme) - order.get(b.theme));

console.log(quote);
```

Answer (score -1):

To sort an array of objects, you can use:

```
quotes.sort(function(a,b) {
   return (a.theme > b.theme) ? 1 : ((b.theme > a.theme) ? -1 : 0);
});
```